# headless cli scripting (in my case, bash, Ubuntu 20)

Tags: python, php, node.js, command-line-interface

I'm curious if there is a way to write scripts in php, python, or nodejs that interact with a virtual command line interface as if you were typing on a keyboard, and which reads all characters sent to the screen, even if the command you called starts its own separate process (thus bypassing the stdin/stdout streams).

Something analogous to a headless web browsing library but for a cli such as bash.

I tried doing this with macro scripts but that involved precise positioning of the window so that the mouse could select and copy the correct text.

Edit (response to Barmar):  like an "except" script but using something like php so writing complex scripts is easier.

Comment: This is generally done using Expect scripts. There are similar libraries for other languages.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a REPL. [Laravel Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#tinker) implements this for example, via [psysh](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh).

Comment: `expect` scripts can be quite sophisticated.  Have you read about them?  `Python` could do it, but I would never use PHP for a project like this.  Wrong problem domain.

Comment: I've used an except script to automate handling of the "accept new fingerprint" dialogue of the "ssh" utility for a list of new devices, but not much else. If the output of except turns out to be visible by programs that call it, then I might be able to use it as an interface for the CLI that combines the I/O streams. Writing everything I need in something like an except script would probably require the sort of inspired dedication that made me think it was a good idea to duplicate one of my undergrad thesis computations in a 1M cell Excel spreadsheet.